# dictionary issue--reference-by-object/value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a problem I fixed with intuition without really understanding the underlying issue. I didn't even know about the `.copy()` method; I just used the IDE's auto-complete to find something. I was wondering if you could help me understand what's going on with the references and memory addresses. Is this a reference-by-value issue or whatev? I'm a very new programmer learning `Python` as my first language. This is an abstraction of what I did:

```
dictionary_short = entries
dictionary_medium = dictionary_short
dictionary_medium.update(more_entries)
dictionary_long = dictionary_medium
dictionary_long.update(even_more_entries)
print(dictionary_short)
# *prints contents of long<!!!>dictionary*
```

So I did:

```
dictionary_short = entries
dictionary_medium = dictionary_short.copy()
dictionary_medium.update(more_entries)
dictionary_long = dictionary_medium.copy()
dictionary_long.update(even_more_entries)
print(dictionary_short)
# *prints contents of short dictionary only*
```

Comment: `dictionary_medium = dictionary_short` simply gives an additional name to an existing object.  Changes made via one name are equally visible via the other name.

Comment: Just read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
This is good...

Answer (score 0):

```
D={}

copy(...) method of builtins.dict instance
     D.copy() -> a shallow copy of D
```

what copy does is it [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html) the data.  so when you do `b=a.copy()` b contains a whole data same as it. if you update b say `b.updtae(c)` then b got different then a. if you dont use copy and update b only, then updated values also refect on a.

below are example

```
a={1:2}

# when not using copy
b=a
print("printing b and a ",b,a)
# output 
# printing b and a  {1: 2} {1: 2}
b.update({2:3}) # updateing b
print("updated value of b",b)
# output updated value of b {1: 2, 2: 3}
print(" printing a ", a) # a and b has save value
 #output  printing a  {1: 2, 2: 3}
a={1:2}
# when using copy
b=a.copy()
print("printing a and b ",a,b)
#output printing a and b  {1: 2} {1: 2} 
b.update({2:3})
print(" updated value of b ",b)
# output updated value of b  {1: 2, 2: 3} 
print("value of a ", a) # b and a have differnet value
#output value of a  {1: 2}
```